# Submeter formulário com botões fora dele

Tags: jquery

Tenho o seguinte formulário

```
<form method='post' name='checkbox_form' id='checkbox_form' onsubmit='return validate()' action=''>
..............
..............
<input name='salvar' type='submit' value='Salvar'>
<input name='gravar' type='submit' value='Gravar'>
</form>
```

e no PHP, dependendo do botão clicado, a variável `$pasta` assume o devido valor corretamente.

```
    if (isset($_POST["gravar"])||isset($_POST["gravar2"])){
        $pasta="favoritas/";
    }else{
        $pasta="usuario/";
    }
```

Além disso tem dois botões que irão, em uma determinada situação, aparecer dentro de um modal

```
<div style=\"display:none\">
    <div id=\"ajax2\" class=\"ajax2\">
    <input name='salvar2' type='button' id='salvar' value='Salvar'>
    <input name='gravar2' type='button' id='gravar' value='Gravar'>
    </div>
</div>
```

Para submeter o formulário com os botões do modal utilizei o seguinte script:

```
$("#salvar").click(function() {
    $("#checkbox_form").submit();
});
$("#gravar").click(function() {
    $("#checkbox_form").submit();
});
```

**O problema:** qualquer que seja o botão clicado no modal a variável `$pasta` assume o valor `usuario/` da condição `else` do PHP, ou seja, nada de `isset`

**A pergunta**: Como posso fazer executar a condicional no PHP corretamente clicando nos botões do modal?

Comment: Uma possibilidade seria em vez de botão no modal, fazer <label for="id_do_botao> - Quando você clica num label for, o botão é acionado (é uma espécie de "controle remoto"). Ai seria o caso de estilizar o label pra parecer botão (tou apresentando como solução rápida, obviamente que alguém pode postar algo mais elaborado com JS e botão de verdade)

Comment: Pelo que eu me lembre, o PHP só vai conseguir fazer essa comparação em botões do tipo `submit`. Ou seja, ao clicar em `gravar2` ele não vai conseguir recuperar.

Comment: @Everson o <button> clicado também envia seu value. (Só o que foi que foi clicado, praticamente como o submit).

Comment: Pra quem só sabe votar negativo vai uma publicação do `dvd` pra vcs https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75640/votos-negativos-sem-explicacao Repensem e procurem ser mais prestativos!

Comment: Passou pela minha cabeça agora de simplesmente colocar um form no modal e fim de papo!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Em vez de fazer um `submit`, você pode fazer um *click* no botão do formulário. Terá o mesmo efeito de ter clicado diretamente no respectivo botão.

Pode simplificar colocando os dois seletores na mesma função, pegando o `value` do botão clicado, que é o mesmo do `value` do botão:

```
$("#salvar, #gravar").click(function() {
    $("#checkbox_form").find("input[value='"+ $(this).val() +"']").click();
});
```

---

```
Botões da modal:
                                                         ________
                                                         ↓      |
<input name='salvar2' type='button' id='salvar' value='Salvar'> |
<input name='gravar2' type='button' id='gravar' value='Gravar'> |
                                                         ↑      |
Botões do form:                              ____________|______|
                                             ↓           |
<input name='salvar' type='submit' value='Salvar'>       |
<input name='gravar' type='submit' value='Gravar'>       |
                                             ↑___________|
```

Comment: Show de bola,sem trabalho, foi só copiar e colar. Perfeito!!!! Com 3 linhas apenas, hehehe.

Comment: Porque eu não pensei em fazer assim antes de você responder? :)

Comment: às vezes dá branco mesmo :D

Comment: hahaha, eu não iria chegar nesse script nunca, faltando alguns fundamentos!!!

Comment: Mt locco. Tu é o cara mesmo rs..

Comment: Queria entender o negativo para essa resposta e tb para a do @Bacco. E também para minha pergunta. Acho que tem muito mané nesse site. Afinal de contas estamos aqui trabalhando de graça pro site dos gringos ajudando muita gente.

Comment: É a turminha do meta, se alguém de lá diz que peidar no código é performático, certeza de muitos ups. Isso aqui é terra de brasucas!!

Answer (score 3):

Dica: os dois demos usam a excelente ferramenta de debug "[httpbin](http://httpbin.org)" para mostrar os resultados

### Com JS:

Uma solução simples é vincular a ação ao `click()` e não ao submit:

```js
$("#tres").click(function() {
  $("#um").click();
  return false;
});

$("#quatro").click(function() {
  $("#dois").click();
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="https://httpbin.org/post">
  <input id="um"   name='acao' type='submit' value='submit um'>
  <input id="dois" name='acao' type='submit' value='submit dois'>
</form>

<button id='tres'  >Remoto do Um</button>
<button id='quatro'>Remoto do Dois</button>
```

### Com Label:

Essa nem de JS precisa (mas um CSS vai bem pra deixar com cara de botão):

```css
.button {
display:block;
background:#ccc;
margin:4px;
width:150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="https://httpbin.org/post">
  <input id="um"   name='acao' type='submit' value='submit um'>
  <input id="dois" name='acao' type='submit' value='submit dois'>
</form>

<label class="button" for='um'  >Remoto do Um  </label>
<label class="button" for='dois'>Remoto do Dois</label>
```

Comment: gostei da sua resposta

Comment: mas quando clica em um botão ai no executar aparece até o ip do usuário

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo a página que aparece é o destino do form, apenas para você ver o que está sendo enviado. Não é o código da resposta que mostra isso, e sim a página que está recebendo o form. No seu caso, o action= vai ser para o seu código original. É a mesma lógica que o colega de site DVD postou depois de mim e foi aceita (como já previsto), só que muito mais simples e objetiva.

Comment: Sobre o negativo, é um deserviço a outros usuários. Pra minha reputação, não muda nada, mas um dia o clubinho de votos trocados vai cair (ou cansar, pq como diria o capitão nascimento, "nunca serão")

Comment: @DVD Pra começo de conversa, eu não achei que o negativo era seu. Segunda vez que vc vem me acusando, coincidentemente depois de EU tomar negativo. Estranho né.

Comment: Eu sei, a action aponta para https://httpbin.org/post, é que não conhecia esse link e fiquei surpreso.

Comment: E o pessoal continua com a farra do -1 com dois demos funcionais, fiquem tranquilos.

Answer (score 1):

Os valores dos botões de submit não estão sendo enviados **$jQuery.submit()**.
Então você pode passar esses valores por post com *hidden input*, e não pelo *name* do button.

**Ex:**

```
<div style=\"display:none\">
    <div id=\"ajax2\" class=\"ajax2\">
    <input name='salvar2' type='button' id='salvar' value='Salvar'>
    <input name='gravar2' type='button' id='gravar' value='Gravar'>

    <input name='acao' type='hidden' id='acao' value=''>
    </div>
</div>
```

**E no JavaScript:**

```
$("#salvar").click(function() {
    $('#acao').val('salvar');
    $("#checkbox_form").submit();
});
$("#gravar").click(function() {
    $('#acao').val('gravar');
    $("#checkbox_form").submit();
});
```

**Na validação:**

```
if (isset($_POST["acao"]) {
    if ($_POST["acao"] == 'gravar'){
        $pasta="favoritas/";
    }else{
        $pasta="usuario/";
    }
}
```